# HTTP Server: Java dynamic method invocation as an alternative to if conditionals

Tags: java, http, reflection

I'm writing an HTTP server and storing headers in a table by name. I'm wondering what's considered good practice for dealing with these. I'm considering using dynamic method invocation (via reflection) and writing methods to handle specific headers that can be referenced by name. Even though this is hardly best practice from an OOP standpoint, I feel like there might be substantial cost savings in eliminating the if statements and especially given that a good server should scale to deal with substantial load. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Reflection generally would be slower than just using `if` to produce objects to cope with each of possible 11 HTTP methods (`PUT`, `GET`, `POST`, ...), so `if` would scale better.
If you don't want to use ladder of `if` you can built hashmap where key is some HTTP method and value is object which will parse HTTP request for that method

Comment: I like that idea actually. I can map headers to method calls and pass in a pointer to the entire table generated per request. That would certainly be more efficient. For the record, there are 46 possible headers (although I'm only supporting a subset of them for now). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user34531 I would build one table with 11 keys, one key per HTTP method (not header). Then each value is method which will know how to parse HTTP request in respect to it's own HTTP method (which headers are supported by that method) -- this way there will be less complexity.